# error C2228 left of '.setDay' must have a class/struct/union

Tags: c++

My project is a modification of one we built in class. it is supposed to print the date that the user enters and convert it to its number day in the year for example. "February 12" = 43
but it keeps giving me a .setDay error. my teacher instructed i put it there and my code stopped working and he would not help. it is also letting off the error E0299 cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "DayOfYear::DayOfYear" is intended.

modification.cpp

```
    // Headers
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include"DayOfYear.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    // create an instance of a class
    DayOfYear dayOfYearObj("Feburary", 12);

    string month;
    int day;                                        // to hold the day

    // display the purpose of the program
    cout << "This program converts a string into a number representing what\n" <<
        "number in the year the date falls on as well as the day before and after the date provided.\n";

    // get the unout from the user
    cout << "\nEnter in a month and a date: ";
    cin >> month, day;

    dayOfYearObj;

    // diplsy the object
    dayOfYearObj.print();

    cout << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

DayOfYear.h

```
    #pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class DayOfYear
{
private:
    int day;

public:
    static int daysAtEndOfMonth[];
    static string monthName[];
    DayOfYear(string, int);
    void print();
    void setDay(int day) { this->day = day; }
};
```

DayOfYear.cpp

```
#include "DayOfYear.h"

int DayOfYear::daysAtEndOfMonth[] = { 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 };

string DayOfYear::monthName[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
"November", "December" };


DayOfYear::DayOfYear(string name, int d)
{
    int day = 0;        //calculated value of date

    if (name == "January" )
    {
        setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "February")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[0] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d); 
    }

    else if (name == "March")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[1] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "April")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[2] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "May")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[3] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "June")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[4] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "July")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[5] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "August")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[6] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "September")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[7] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "October")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[8] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if  (name == "November")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[9] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }

    else if (name == "December")
    {
        day = daysAtEndOfMonth[10] + d;
        DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Number is out of range." << endl;
    }
}


// dayofYear print convert and print day of year
void::DayOfYear::print()
{
    int month = 0;
    while (daysAtEndOfMonth[month] < day)
        month = (month + 1) % 12;
    if (month == 0)
        cout << "January" << day << endl << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << endl << monthName[month] << " " << day - daysAtEndOfMonth[month - 1]
            << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you got it right for the "January" case. Why not replicate that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setDay` is not static it needs to be called from an instance of the class, so you cannot call it like

```
DayOfYear::DayOfYear.setDay(d);
```

Instead, you'd call it off of `this`

```
this->setDay(d);
```

which is implicitly what is called within a class method, so you can just drop the `this->`

```
setDay(d);
```

In fact, you do this correctly for `"January"`, then incorrect in the latter months.